# Automorphisms of vector spaces and the complex numbers without choice

Tags: set-theory, fields, axiom-of-choice, vector-spaces, automorphisms

In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without the Axiom of Choice (AC), it is consistent to say that there are models in which:

1. there are vector spaces without a basis;
2. the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ only has two automorphisms (identity and complex conjugation).

Before I even ask my main question, I want to ask two "pre-questions" (as I am not a logician):

- is my formulation "in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without the Axiom
  of Choice (AC), it is consistent to say that there are models in
  which ..." formally correct? (And if not, what is a formal correct
  statement ?);
- for the second statement above, what is a precise reference in which I can find this statement?

Now for my main question: is it also true that it is consistent to say that there are models of ZF set theory without AC, in which every vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ *has* a base (or even stronger: in which *dimension* is well defined), and in which $\mathbb{C}$ also has precisely two field automorphisms?

Comment: "Every vector space has a basis" implies choice; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207990/vector-spaces-and-ac

Comment: To continue @KevinCasto's comment, just in case it's not clear: and once you have choice, you're in ZFC, so you can cook up many automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Although I don't think it's known that "every vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ has a basis" implies choice.

Comment: Oh, I see. So how should I understand @KevinCastos comment?

Comment: Ah fair enough, I didn't read Blass' proof closely enough (it relies on function fields over $\mathbb C$ also having this property). Still, it does in any case seem like a result worth mentioning in the context of the question!

Comment: @KevinCasto Blass' proof constructs a field that will be associated with a choice function over a given set (more precisely, a witness for Multiple choice,) so we cannot say the existence of a basis over a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space implies choice from Blass' proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but it is too long to be a comment.

Let $B(F)$ for field $F$ be the statement "every vector space over $F$ has a basis" and let $AL19(F)$ be the statement "for every vector space $V$ over $F$, every generating subset of $V$ contains a basis", $AL20(F)$ means "for every vector space $V$ over $F$, every independent subset of $V$ is contained in a basis".

In 2012 Paul Howard and Eleftherios Tachtsis said in [1] that both:

- There exists a field $F$ such that "$B(F)\implies AC$"
- There exists a field $F$ such that "$B(F)\;\not\!\!\!\implies AC$"

Are open, in particular *if the answer of your question is positive, then it is an open problem*.

On the other hand, Paul Howard had proven in [2] that $(∃F\ s.t.\ AL19(F))⇒AC$, in particular, the strengthening of $B(ℂ)$ to $AL19(ℂ)$ does imply AC and hence imply that there are wild automorphisms for $ℂ$.

Similarly, both [1] and [2] claim that in [3,4] it was proven that $(∃F\ s.t.\ AL20(F))⇒MC$ (which over ZF implies $AC$), and hence the dual strengthenin of $B(ℂ)$ to $AL20(ℂ)$ also imply that there are wild automorphisms for $ℂ$ (although from quick glance over [3,4] I couldn't see this result, a proof of this result, together with the result of the previous paragraph can be found in [5]).

> [1] *Howard, Paul; Tachtsis, Eleftherios*, [**On vector spaces over specific fields without choice**](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.201200049), Math. Log. Q. 59, No. 3, 128-146 (2013). [ZBL1278.03082](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1278.03082).

> [2] *Howard, Paul*, [**Bases, spanning sets, and the axiom of choice**](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.200610043), Math. Log. Q. 53, No. 3, 247-254 (2007). [ZBL1121.03064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1121.03064).

> [3] *Armbrust, M. K.*, [**An algebraic equivalent of a multiple choice axiom**](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-74-2-145-146), Fundam. Math. 74, 145-146 (1972). [ZBL0234.04011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0234.04011).

> [4] *Bleicher, M. N.*, [**Some theorems on vector spaces and the axiom of choice**](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-54-1-95-107), Fundam. Math. 54, 95-107 (1964). [ZBL0118.25503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0118.25503).

> [5] Rubin, H., & Rubin, J. E. (1985). Algebraic Forms. In [*Equivalents of the axiom of choice, II*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/equivalents-of-the-axiom-of-choice-ii/rubin/978-0-444-87708-6) (p. 122). North-Holland.